# Should I use singular or plural in this sentence?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Mrs V, together with her children, jog or jogs in the park every weekend.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To choose between the singular 'jogs' and the plural 'jog', delete the parenthetical clause "together with her children", and consider each verb form.

Mrs V jog in the park
Mrs V jogs in the park

Which one is right? The second one. Mrs V, she of the curiously short surname, is one person, a singular entity.

Comment: Indeed! And if the children were joint subjects, it would be otherwise - "Mrs V and her children jog in the park". This is a handy illustration of the difference between additional subjects and adverbials/prepositional phrases etc, which can be hard for the novice to distinguish - especially when they are parenthetical.